# How does one cite WHO apps?

Tags: citations

The World Health Organization (WHO) has a number of apps, I felt I should keep the question rather general in order to prevent people from attempting to close this question for being too narrow, but I really am interested in how I would cite the diagnostic criteria in [ICD-10](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2010/en) in Vancouver style.

Comment: There is nothing special about The WHO. The WHO releases the ICD-10 as an [electronic book](http://www.whopress.us/Books/BookDetail.aspx?productID=234484), a [printed book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/international-statistical-classification-diseases-problems/dp/9241548347), and a [website](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2010/en). you should cite the version you used.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel commented, "there is nothing special about The WHO." As with any source, cite in accordance with the citation style  you are using. For Vancouver style, two online guides are [here](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/library/resources/documents/vancouverreferencing.pdf) and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7256/?amp=&depth=2). Find the section relevant to the source you are using, (electronic book, print book or website), and use the recommended format.